# how to cast a i64 Series/chunkedArray into f64 or String in polars-rust?

Tags: python-polars, rust-polars

With a Series which comes from a column of DataFrame, how could cast it into a f64 Series or f64 ChunkedArray? It seems `.apply_cast_numeric(|v| v as f64)` got failure.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do something like this?

```rust
// coerce 'QTY' column from i32 to f32. df is mutable.
df.may_apply(QTY, |s: &Series| s.cast(&DataType::Float32))?;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the `cast` method.

```rust
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let df = df! [
        "Id" => [1i64,2],
    ]
    .unwrap();

    let ca_f64 = df
        .column("Id")
        .unwrap()
        .i64()
        .unwrap()
        .cast(&datatypes::DataType::Float64)
        .unwrap();

    // If you want to cast it to string
    // let ca_string = df
    //     .column("Id")
    //     .unwrap()
    //     .i64()
    //     .unwrap()
    //     .cast(&datatypes::DataType::String)
    //     .unwrap();


    println!("{ca_f64}");
    // println!("{ca_string}");
}
```